# How to use regular expression with mvn test command

Tags: java, maven

i am trying to use below command. I have

- Mytest1_test.java,
- Mytest2_test.java,
- Mytest3_test.java,
- Mytest4_test.java,
- Mytest5_test.java,

I want to run first 4 at once.

```
mvn test -Dtest=Mytest[1-4]_test
```

but it is giving me no test to run.

Can some one plz advice...?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
mvn -Dtest=Mytest*_test test
```

Comment: Thanks
mvn -Dtest=Mytest*_test test

Comment: As i mentioned in my que "I want to run first 4 at once".

But mvn -Dtest=Mytest*_test test runs all five tests.

Please advice on how run ranged/selected test with mvn test.

Comment: Not aware of any way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

For the regex to match, you may need to add the package name - just prefixing with `.*` might be enough (you can try with and without the `.*` suffix - I used it to match '.class' under JUnit4):

```
mvn test "-Dtest=%regex[.*Mytest[1-4]_test.*]"
```

Note that I've used quotes around the whole *-Dtest* argument to make it more readable when we add more test combinations.

**Adding a Problematic Test**

When we have a problematic test that fails only in certain combinations then we can add a comma, and a space and another test inside the quotes (`"`) but after the `]`.

Let's say `Mytest5_test` fails with tests 1, 2 and 3. We can use regex for the first 3, followed by a comma and standard matching for `Mytest5_test`, with a * if we need to catch any packages:

```
mvn test "-Dtest=%regex[.*Mytest[1-3]_test.*], *Mytest5_test"
```

*Strictly speaking we don't need the quotes, but without them we'd need to remove the space between the different tests which would make the command less readable.*

**Find a Conflicting Test**

When our test fails when run in combination with others (static mocks are often the culprit) we also can use regex to help find conflicting tests.

To run all the tests in packages beginning with my.co.[a-m], and `Mytest5_test` we can use:

```
mvn test "-Dtest=%regex[.*my.co.[a-m].*], *Mytest5_test"
```

If I recall correctly, JUnit 4 needs slash separators, JUnit 5 needs dot separators and with Spock just has class name without the package. Using `.*` and the wildcard single character `.` as in the regex above will work whether test names have slashes or dots for package names.

Then change the regex to run other tests (e.g. [n-z]) and keep narrowing down until you have the combination you need.

Answer (score 1):

The tricks is to use * character and to exclude other tests with ! character as below.

```
mvn test -Dtest=Mytest*_test,!Mytest5_test
```

According to the [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html) of Maven surefire plugin, the command below should work with a regular expression but it don't seem to work (no test executed).

```
mvn test -Dtest=%regex[Mytest[1-4]_test]
```

Tested on Windows 7 with Maven Surefire plugin 3.x.

Comment: you might just need to add the package name (or `'.*`) at the start of your regex.

Answer (score 0):

If You have got tests in directories, you can launch all tests from one of them by writing in regexp, eg. for all tests from subdirectory '/doc' in qa/src/test/java/com/frax/doc/:

```
mvn -Dtest=*/doc/* test
```